# Number of questions and answers written by a user across all sites

Tags: support, profile-page, stackexchange.com

How do I find the total number of questions and answers written by a user across all Stack Exchange sites? A user's stackexchange.com profile page's "account" tab lists the number of questions and answers by site. How do I see the total number of questions and the total number of answers across all sites?

Answer (score 5):

**You can use the API**

[Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) has a dedicated endpoint for returning information about network users when given a list user account ids (note that this is not the id you see on the network sites when opening someone's profile page - it is the one found in the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5065111/flux)): `/users/{ids}/associated`.

For an interactive experience, try playing around with the snippet below (note that the API has a daily limit of 10 000 requests per IP even with the key so there is a slight chance of running out of quota for the day):

<sub>Badge counts added to match [Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289905/sebastian-simon)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369795/786798)</sub>

```js
const API_BASE = "https://api.stackexchange.com";
const API_VER = 2.3;
const API_KEY = "zhhhBNmsqZLZ967tc2dn8w((";

const getUserAccounts = async(id, {
  page = 1,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const url = new URL(`${API_BASE}/${API_VER}/users/${id}/associated`);
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    page: page.toString(),
    ...rest,
  }).toString();

  const res = await fetch(url.toString());
  if (!res.ok) return [];

  const {
    items = [], has_more = false, backoff
  } = await res.json();

  if (backoff) {
    await delay(backoff * 1e3);
    return getUserAccounts(id, {
      page,
      ...rest
    });
  }

  if (has_more) {
    items.push(...(await getUserAccounts(id, {
      page: page + 1,
      ...rest,
    })));
  }

  return items;
};

const makeCell = (content) => {
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.append(content);
  return td;
};

const makeRow = (columns) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const cells = columns.map(makeCell);
  tr.append(...cells);
  return tr;
};

const makeLink = (url, label) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.href = url;
  a.innerText = label;
  return a;
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  const input = document.getElementById("account_id");

  const submit = document.getElementById("search");
  submit.addEventListener("click", async() => {
    const {
      value: accountId
    } = input;

    const report = document.querySelector("#preview > tbody");

    const accounts = await getUserAccounts(accountId, {
      key: API_KEY,
      filter: "*AXic)yfHtd",
    });

    const rows = accounts
      .sort((a, b) => b.answer_count - a.answer_count)
      .map(({
        account_id,
        answer_count,
        question_count,
        site_name,
        site_url,
        user_id,
        badge_counts
      }) => makeRow([
        makeLink(`${site_url}/users/${user_id}`, site_name),
        question_count,
        answer_count,
        Object.entries(badge_counts).map(([t,c]) => `${c} ${t}`).join(", ")
      ]));

    report.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((r) => r.remove());
    
    const totals = accounts.reduce((a, { 
      answer_count,
      question_count,
      badge_counts: { bronze, silver, gold }
    }) => {
      a[1] += question_count;
      a[2] += answer_count;
      
      const [,,,badges] = a;
      badges[0] += bronze,
      badges[1] += silver,
      badges[2] += gold
      return a;
    }, ["Network-wide",0,0, [0,0,0]]);
    
    const [,,,[sn, ag, au]] = totals;
    totals[3] = `${sn} bronze, ${ag} silver, ${au} gold`;
    
    const total = makeRow(totals);
    report.append(total, ...rows);

    report.closest("table").classList.remove("hidden");
  });

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}

caption,
label {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
}

table {
  margin-top: 4vh;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="account_id">User Account Id</label>
  <input id="account_id" type="text" title="Account Id" placeholder="12345" value="15810379" />
  <button id="search" type="button">Get Info</button>
</form>

<table id="preview" class="hidden" cellspacing="0">
  <caption>Stack Exchange Post Activity</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Account</th>
      <th>Questions</th>
      <th>Answers</th>
      <th>Badges</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to do this with JavaScript (via DOM traversal):

1. Go to [your accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts) or any other network profile accounts page,
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open your browser console,
3. Copy-paste the following JavaScript code into it (works in Chrome 80+, Edge 80+, Firefox 74+):

   ```js
   const badgeNames = {
       "badge1": "goldBadges",
       "badge2": "silverBadges",
       "badge3": "bronzeBadges"
     };

   console.table(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".account-container .account-number, .account-container .badgecount"), ({ textContent: value, nextElementSibling: statKey, previousElementSibling: badgeKey }) => [ // Destructure each element that has a count of something to the count itself and its neighboring elements.
       statKey?.textContent?.trim() // The “unit” of various stats is written after the count.
         ?? badgeNames[badgeKey?.className], // For badges, we’re looking for an (invisible) element before the count.
       Number(value.split(",").join("")) || 0 // Remove commas, convert to number, special handling for Area 51 where the “number” is “-”. Replace `.split(",").join("")` by `.replaceAll(",", "")` in supporting browsers.
     ])
     .filter(([ key ]) => key) // If there are no badges, no key can be produced; remove these cases.
     .reduce((result, [ key, value ]) => {
       result[key] += value;

       return result;
     }, {
       reputation: 0,
       goldBadges: 0,
       silverBadges: 0,
       bronzeBadges: 0,
       questions: 0,
       answers: 0
     }));
   ```
4. See the result printed in the console in a table layout: in your case, it looks like this:

   | (Position) | Value |
   | --- | --- |
   | reputation | 42343 |
   | goldBadges | 11 |
   | silverBadges | 146 |
   | bronzeBadges | 581 |
   | questions | 812 |
   | answers | 283 |

I’ve also included the badge counts and the reputation counts, although adding up reputation may be … difficult to interpret.